# How do I turn off spell check?

Tags: spellchecker

I write mostly in swedish and every. single. word. has a squiggly red line under it!!! It's driving me nuts! Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Uncheck `Check spelling as you type` in `Preferences>Interface`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). 2) When you see good questions and answers, please vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Please remember to eventually accept an answer, that (best) solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 11):

You might also try the following:

- Go to the menu item: Format > Option Inspector
- Go to Editing Options > Private Editing Options
- Set `IgnoreSpellCheck` to `True`

Alternatively, you can set this same option using [SetOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) from a notebook by executing

- `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, IgnoreSpellCheck -> True]`

Comment: I push up this question as I have the exact same problem.
I tried the tricks mentioned in that post but my text is still red! [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIHT6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIHT6.png)