# Disable spell checking for unknown language

Tags: front-end, spellchecker

Let's say I am typing in a language *Mathematica* does not recognize for any reason. How do I make the software to understand that it should not try to spellcheck this notebook? It is annoying to see the entire workbook underlined.

Also, I know this language is added, because others have it but I don't. Preferably I would like in the future for *Mathematica* to use that language spelling when it does know the language.

Also, I don't want to do this for my interface, only this notebook, so that when I share with students not everything is underlined.

**Clarification**:

I know that i can do changes in the front end:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, IgnoreSpellCheck -> True]
```

But this is not an acceptble solution. Because by running this I would have now effectively permanently disabled spellecheker for a really big number of people as this is a shared resource.

In order for this to be even remotely feasible the change needs to be temporary. If my notebook is closed it should return the settings. Preferably also once the user switches another notebook the settings should also resume like they where before. Also as a bonus it should not do this if it knows how to correct the language. After all its their settings not mine!

Surely there is a event or some other mechanism that lest me clean up the mess i made.

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144448/how-do-i-turn-off-spell-check?rq=1.

Comment: The above post is close, but tells how I turn it off for my editor not how to do it for workbook so that other users benefit. I was aware of that before I asked.

Comment: Read carefully the answer from the cited link, especially `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, IgnoreSpellCheck -> True]`. Also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123486/set-spell-checking-language?rq=1 may be useful.

Comment: @user64494 yeah that solves my frontend problem. BUt it does not solve the students frontend problem. I can not go and turn of a feature on randpm persons options they would never know whats wrong. I need to also clean up after myself.

Comment: THis is also a PR issue. I would like to get people using Mathematica instead of pen and paper but stuff like this is really makeing it hard for me to get enough good will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpellCheck is done on cells having the option `LanguageCategory->"NaturalLanguage"`. This appears in the style definition of the default stylesheet (Default.nb) for all text based styles (i.e. Text, Section, SubSection, etc.). What you can do is create your own stylesheet derived from Default.nb (or other stylesheets).

1. Create a new notebook
2. Select `Format>Edit Stylesheet`
3. Choose the style "Text"
4. Select the cell and choose `Cell>Show Expression` in the menu
5. Modify the expression by adding the option: `LanguageCategory->None`
6. `Cell>Show Expression` to resume normal display
7. Repeat for other text based  styles
8. Click the `Install stylesheet...` button and select a name for the new style sheet (such as **NoSpellCheck**) and save. The name will appear in the menu under `Format>Stylesheet`. You can then apply the stylesheet to any other notebook.

Step3:
[image]
Step 4:
[image]
Step 5:
[image]

**UPDATE:**: Another possibility is to add the option `ShowAutoSpellCheck->False` instead of using `LanguageCategory->None`.

Comment: This will do. Atleast it is notebook only. I really wish setting a language mathematica does not know would disable spelling instead of setting it to automatic. That way the spelling could appear later. Why try when its known you will fail.